# Do you like head coverings?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

### Get ready for head coverings!

Since the current voting is 5/0 and nobody has objected or given reasons why we should avoid it, we are going to **opt in**.  Remember, if hats are not your thing, you can individually turn them off and after 3 weeks they will be gone from our site.   Let's get ready to cover our (avatars') heads!

---

Last year, the Gaming Stack Exchange site had a special, limited-time [promotion](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) called the [Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/).  The upshot was that users could earn decorations for their avatar that looked like this:

[image: A collection of hats.]

This year, Stack Exchange has opened the promotion to any site that would like to **opt-in**.

So we need to decide before November 28 if we want to be a part of the game this year.  As I see it there are:

## Pros

1. We can look forward to something novel and fun around the site from **19 December 2012** to **4 January 2013** to keep people coming back.  Last year we experienced a lull over the holidays.
2. The things we do to earn hats will *also* be beneficial to the site.
3. The entire promotion is entirely **optional** for individual users.  If you hate hats, you can turn the whole thing off.
4. It might help us bring our causal and new users into the fold.  People are drawn to other people who don't mind a little levity once in a while.

and:

## Cons

1. Some people might get the wrong idea from some of the hats.  Even though Santa hats aren't really Christian and the halo is just for fun, it *could* send the wrong sorts of messages.

[Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1420/914) has also raised a meta question that I will be watching, but our decision is entirely separate from any other site.  If this seems like a good idea to you, please vote this question up.  If you think we should skip it, vote it down.  If you have any concerns or encouragements, comment or answer.

What do y'all think of the [head covering](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/546/68) promotion?

Comment: It should be mentioned that last year's promtions were as inclusive as possible of different winter celebrations (note Santa hat *and* dreidel)

Comment: What are 'causal users'? ;)

Comment: @JackDouglas: They are even more rare than "correlation users", which is why we want them to stick around. ;-)  [I thought](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161891/1438) last year went rather well, by the way.