# Let's have a second opinion!

Tags: discussion, challenge, unanswered-questions

It's been a while since I issued a [challenge](/questions/tagged/challenge) and now that [hats](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402/do-you-like-head-coverings#) are over, it's about time for something new.  In the past, I've focused on generating new questions, but this time I'd like to focus on generating new answers.  Right at the moment, [our answer ratio](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1817/biblical-hermeneutics) stands at 1.9, that's "Okay" (officially), but for a site that blends a [wide variety](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161733/1438) of hermeneutical traditions, it's not as good as we can be doing.

[Lately](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/417/68), we've been chewing over the problem of how to avoid looking like a Christian site and while there are many things we can be doing, modeling the sorts of answers we'd like to see is perhaps the most effective thing we can be doing.  The [voting system](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/132/68) seems to work well for questions that have multiple answers, but it can't do much when there's only one answer.  So let's make sure we don't have a [single-party system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-party_state)!

---

The [new search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/1438) allows us to find these questions.  For instance, if you want to see all the open questions that have exactly one answer, enter the following in a search box:

```
answers:1..1 closed:no
```

At the moment, that turns up [360 results](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=answers:1-1%20closed:no).  Even limiting to questions without accepted answers returns [142 results](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=answers:1-1%20closed:no%20hasaccepted:no), so you might want to limit yourself to a particular tag:

```
answers:1..1 closed:no hasaccepted:no [tag-name]
```

To further restrict the search, you could include [questions you've asked](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers:1..1%20closed:no%20hasaccepted:no%20user:me):

```
answers:1..1 closed:no hasaccepted:no -user:me
```

However, there seems to be no way to *exclude* yourself; there's no negation option and the range option doesn't work for user ID.  I've submitted [another feature request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163428/1438), but it's likely to be a bit trickier to implement.

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to find open questions with just one answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161838/1438 "Let's see how fast MSE comes up with a solution!")

Comment: @GoneQuiet try this: `answers:1..1 closed:no hasaccepted:no -user:208` (no guarantees)

Comment: @JonEricson wouldn't adding the `-` before `user` be an exclusion? There *is* an exclusion option by adding `-` before any of these I thought....

Comment: @Dan O'Day: That seems to only exclude answers with the _string_ "user:208".  See my [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163428/1438 "+13 at the moment.").

Comment: ahh, I see. Thanks for clarifying