# Do you like head coverings, 2013?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Last year, Stack Exchange opened up a promotion previously run on the Gaming Stack Exchange site to any site that would like to **opt-in**, and [we did](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/402/43).

[image: A collection of hats.]

*They may or may not look like this ^^^^^^^^^^*

So we need to decide before November 28 if we want to be a part of the game this year.  As I see it there are:

## Pros

1. We can look forward to something novel and fun around the site from **16 December 2013** to **3 January 2014** to keep people coming back. Two years ago we experienced a lull over the holidays. Last year, [things were awesome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161891/166851).
2. The things we do to earn hats will *also* be beneficial to the site.
3. The entire promotion is entirely **optional** for individual users.  If you hate hats, you can turn the whole thing off.
4. It might help us bring our casual and new users into the fold.  People are drawn to other people who don't mind a little levity once in a while.

and:

## Cons

1. Some people might get the wrong idea from some of the hats.  Santa hats and halos are just for fun here, but could conceivably upset some folk.
2. We are a serious site and some may think hats just don't mix with hermeneutics.

If this seems like a good idea to you, please vote this question up.  If you think we should skip it, vote it down.  If you have any concerns or encouragements, comment or answer.

---

<sup>*Yes this is a blatant cut'n'paste of Jon's post last year*</sup>

Comment: Since the current voting is 6/0 and nobody has objected or given reasons why we should avoid it, we have **opted in**.  Remember, if hats are not your thing, you can individually turn them off and after 3 weeks they will be gone from our site :)